# Manipulating select option selected value in DOM several times without page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I am in an unfortunate position where I need to be able to copy entire blocks of HTML without the page reloading using javascript/jquery, including inputs and selects.

I have most of it working, but I'm stumped on the selects.  In order for it to "copy" properly so the copy displays the selected value of where its copying from, I need to explicitly set the attribute "selected" on the copy from select.  The problem is, if I change the value on a select that I will copy from, the previous selections "selected" attribute remains, and I don't know how to get rid of it.

Here is a link to the fiddle and below is the basic test to show you what I mean:  [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/szfiddle/n4wt4hrn/1/).  You'll need to inspect element on the select list and show all of the option tags.

1. Make a selection
2. Hit the Enter button
3. Observe the selected attribute go on the option you chose
4. Choose a different option
5. Hit the enter button
6. Observe that now two options have the selected attribute.  At this point I need to get rid of the selected attribute from the step 3 observation

HTML:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <select>
        <option value="">Select One</option>    
        <option value="test1">Test1</option>
        <option value="test2">Test2</option>
        <option value="test3">Test3</option>
        <option value="test4">Test4</option>    
      </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<button onclick="enterTest()">Enter</button>
```

Javascript

```
function enterTest(){
    var $selectedOption = $("select").children(":selected");
    $selectedOption.attr("selected","selected");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to deal with `option`s and `selected` attribute.

If the values are unique,

```
var $select = $("select");
function enterTest(){
    $select.clone().val($select.val()).appendTo('body');
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/n4wt4hrn/2/)

Otherwise, use `selectedIndex`:

```
$select.clone().prop('selectedIndex', $select.prop('selectedIndex'))
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/n4wt4hrn/3/)